# Careers at the National Research Council of Italy and difference from the university system

Tags: career-path, job-search, job, early-career, italy

What is the organization of the National Research Council of Italy (CNR)? In particular, I'd like to know

- How does one get a position there? I assume there are public competitions (as for university positions), but I've never seen an announcement: Are they very rare or just not advertised as much?
- What is the career progression in the CNR? I've seen people being called "Technologist", "Researcher", "Senior Researcher", and "Research Director" within them: What are the differences/seniorities/career progression mechanisms?
- What are the other differences between an academic career at a university and at a CNR unit? In particular, in terms of teaching load, administrative tasks, and salary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, CNR is a giant entity with a hundred units, spread across all Italy, and with about eight-nine thousand researchers. It is therefore quite different from a university.

1. Yes, there are public competitions. All available calls can be found [here](https://selezionionline.cnr.it/jconon/). These calls are also published, like all public calls in Italy for whatever position, in the [*Gazzetta Ufficiale 4ª Serie Speciale - Concorsi ed Esami*](https://www.gazzettaufficiale.it/30giorni/concorsi) (in Italian).
2. In principle, technologist and researcher are two different paths. A technologist is a kind of senior technician. However, the distinction between the two paths is frequently fuzzy. For researchers, the career progression is *Researcher* (equivalent to an Assistant Professor in the university system), *Senior Researcher* (equivalent to an Associate Professor), and *Research Director* (equivalent to a Full Professor). For technologists, the career progression is *Technologist*, *Senior Technologist* and *Technologist Director*. You move from one level to another through competitions. These are all permanent positions.
3. CNR staff does not have any teaching duties, because it's a research only institution. Some researchers, though, are also affiliated to universities (and some CNR units are hosted by universities) and may teach classes. The salary between CNR and universities is about the same. Within CNR, also the salary between technologists and researchers, at equal level, is about the same. You can find details about the gross salary in [these tables](http://www.dcp.cnr.it/DPUASI/Moduli/Download/Contratti/Costo_Tabellare_Personale_2020.pdf), which are however quite hard to interpret. The salaries for researchers can be found from p. 3 of the linked document. According to my understanding, the levels (abbreviated *Liv.* in the document) correspond to the positions: *Liv III*, Researcher; *Liv II*, Senior Researcher; *Liv I*, Research Director. The *fascia* corresponds to the number of years of employment: one starts from *1ª fascia*, then after three years moves to *2ª fascia*, after five more years to *3ª fascia* and so on (the number of years between each *fascia* is reported [in this page](http://blog.imm.cnr.it/content/64com-uil-rua-cnr-12-11-2018-passaggio-di-fascia-fascia-anticipata)).

Comment: Thank you! What is the path to get promoted between Researcher, Senior Researcher, and Research Director? Is there a habilitation process (as in the French CNRS)?

Comment: @Kei As far as I know, there's no habilitation for CNR (unlike in the university). You apply for a progression when CNR opens a position.

Comment: Thanks! I've also taken a look at the tables, but I couldn't understand much. Could you extract from them the lowest and highest salary (before taxes) for the "Researchers", "Senior Researcher", and "Research Director"?

Comment: Finally, I'd like to ask you: on average, would you say that the number of positions in the CNR in a given town and in a given research area (within mathematics) is more or less than the number of university positions?

Comment: @Kei I've edited the answer to add some explanation on the salary. Beware though that that is anyway the gross salary, and the net salary is not easily predictable. The number of university positions is totally independent from that of the CNR positions.

Comment: Thank you very much! About the location of the CNR, say the "IAC – Istituto per le Applicazioni del Calcolo Mauro Picone" for example, I see that there are four places: Bari, Firenze, Napoli, Roma. Is the application process centralized and then you get to choose the place or does each town have its own positions?

Comment: @Kei Afaik, typically each town has its own positions, but the application process is centralized and all positions are reported in the link of point 1.

Comment: I see, thanks! And you cannot move between one place and another without an additional competion? Also, I forgot to ask a fundamental questions: are the positions permanent? Is "Researcher" a tenure-track job and "Senior Researcher" the tenured one?

Comment: @Kei Those are all permanent positions. Also Researcher is permanent. But CNR has probably also temporary positions.